# Big Query Public Dataset Events/Triggers?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to get a notification whenever new rows are inserted into public dataset? Do BQ datasets/tables support triggers or events for us to use when the data changes?

I am experimenting with public datasets and wish to execute my recomputation logic whenever Google updates a public dataset.
I wish to invoke a CloudFunction to compute something whenever new rows are inserted into noaa_gsod.gsod_2018 public dataset.
Now, it doesn't have to be a fancy serverless target - I am happy to subscribe to a topic on PubSub and use a GCE VM instance to execute my logic, if BQ public dataset can somehow publish such messages to PubSub.
Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to get notified of changes/updates to public dataset.
Would love to hear from the community if anyone has experimented on this matter.
Thanks,
Dheerendra Nath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best option I see so far is to have the process that will execute below query (free of charge) as frequently as you need and based on changes in respective fields invoke whatever logic you have in mind

```
select last_modified_time, row_count
from `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.__TABLES__`
where table_id = 'gsod2018'
```

or you can use [tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/get) API for the same

Unfortunately, Cloud Function triggers on BigQuery tables are not supported nor BigQuery change's notifications are supported

Meantime, you can submit respective feature request in [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, It'd be nice to avoid polling for obvious reasons - need a container to run the polling logic, even though the query itself is free. Unfortunately looks like this might be only option as of now. I'm hopeful as someone might have stumbled upon this requirement and may have tried something, let's see if Google  already has something in Alpha.
Cheers!

Comment: agree with you but as I said  - as of now it looks like the only realistic direction. not aware about any alpha related to this topic. obviously we all hope to have such functionality eventually :o)